# Minimal value of a function involving the closeness of $\arctan$ to $\pi/2$

Tags: real-analysis

It appears that function

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^\infty(\pi/2-\arctan(t))^x dt$$

has a minimum for $x$ near $e$.  Can someone prove this?

Comment: the minimum seems to be at $x$ bit larger than $e$, near 2.7456.

Answer (score 4):

One only has to note that (i) $f$ is strictly convex where it is finite (because the integrand is strictly convex in $x$) and (ii) the values of $f$ at (say) $2740/1000, 2745/1000, 2750/1000$ are $1.96046\ldots>1.96045\ldots< 1.96046\ldots$, respectively. So, the only minimum of $f$ is in the interval $(2740/1000, 2750/1000)$. Of course, this way one can compute the minimum with any degree of accuracy.

---

Here is the graph of the function $f$ over the interval $(2740/1000, 2750/1000)$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica 12.0 says

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(Pi/2 - ArcTan[t])^x, {t, 0, Infinity}];
NMinimize[{f[x], x > 0}, x]
```

$$ \{1.96046,\{x\to 2.74563\}\}$$